# Discord JS Music bot - .message.member.voiceChannel.join() not working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a music bot in Discord.JS. However, I am getting an error when I debug the code. 
Here is the code:

```
var channel = message.member.voiceChannel;

        if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) channel.join().then(function(connection){
            play(connection, message);
        });
```

**play** is a function that I have created higher up in my code.

The error that I am getting is:

```
                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ryans\Desktop\STATICbot\index.js:112:56)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\ryans\Desktop\STATICbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\ryans\Desktop\STATICbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\ryans\Desktop\STATICbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:330:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\ryans\Desktop\STATICbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:293:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\ryans\Desktop\STATICbot\node_modules\ws\lib\EventTarget.js:99:16)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
```

I have tried to change **member** in **message.member.voiceChannel** to **members** but that didn't work.

I have also tried to have **message.member.voiceChannel** outside of a variable and before **.join()** instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: is the member in the voice channel?

Comment: @DakshMiglani Not when I run the command, no.

Comment: what the error code says is, that the user who sent the message is not in any voice channel, so the bot can't join the channel.

Comment: @DakshMiglani That fixed it! Could you add that as an answer to my question so I can select that you've answered my question, please?

Comment: Alright, I'll do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So what the error code says is, that the user who sent the message is not in any voice channel, so the bot can't join the channel.

Possible Solutions:

1. Join a Channel and then send the message.
2. if channel is not found, then join a preset channel.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using something similar to this in my discord bot code

```
voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;

voiceChannel.join().then(function (connection) {

}
```